# Prevent the next word from being capitalized after pausing dictation on Galaxy S8

Tags: samsung, voice-recognition, text-input

When you pause while dictating to a Samsung Galaxy S8 mobile phone, and resume dictating, how do you prevent the next word from being capitalized?